# Firebase database retrieving data from comma seperated list

Tags: javascript, sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store the comma separated ids on a child node & how can I filter data as in sql we can use IN clause to fetch data any possibility in firebase to perform this kind of operation in firebase database.

Please suggest any possible solution for this.

Comment: Don't store data a comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have the equivalent of SQLs `IN` clause. It also doesn't have a way to find a substring in a value. So the data model you are looking to use, doesn't allow the use-case you want. As usual with NoSQL databases, the solution is to pick a data model that *does* allow your use-case..

The most likely cause I know for the structure you describe is to associate the child node with a bunch of categories. If that is your case, read my answer here for a proper data structure: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

This is one of the cases where the new Cloud Firestore database offers better querying support, since it recently added a feature to [efficiently test if an array contains a certain value](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s)). If you're only just getting started with your project, you might want to check if Firestore is a better fit for your use-cases.